issue with vault ui: oidc role not found
I am facing an issue on vault integrated with keycloak, when i a try to use a role to sign in it appears that there is a misbehavior / bug, the last character of the role id is missing in the payload
for example:
i am using the admin-role which is existing in oidc vault roles,
on sign to oidc provider, the payload of the request made to vault from vault ui contains:
{
    "redirect_uri": "https://VAULT.DOMAIN/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback",
    "role": "admin-rol"
}

which is not correct -e- is missing, this leads to a 400 http error Bad request, role admin-rol could not be found
for more context:
Vault version (1.13.3) deployed on docker-compose
i checked up in hashicorp/vault github repo, and didn't notice any issue about that
i am also trying a newer versions to see if it has been fixed since
is anyone facing the same issue ?
